# Android bluetooth get device name

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have multiple Bluetooth devices from a vendor. When I paired my device it takes the same friendly name say `"BTDevice"`. Now when i pair all multiple devices I get the same name. in my `ListView`. I cannot show the the address of the device  in my List.I tried renaming the friendly name in Bluetooth settings but it still shows me "BTDevice" as device name when I do `device.getName()` any suggestions to overcome this issue.

Here is the code.

```
private void getDevice(){
ArrayList<String> bondedAdapter = new ArrayList<String>();
 try {
       BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
       Set<BluetoothDevice> bondedSet =   bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();          
       int count = 0;
       if(bondedSet.size() > 0){
          for(BluetoothDevice device : bondedSet){          
          bondedAdapter.add(device.getName()+"\n"+device.getAddress());     
          Log.i("TabInflater", device.getName());
       }
       }else{
        bondedAdapter.add("No Devices");
       }
     } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("TabInflater","Error");
     }
}
```

In my log it says I have paired to (Addresses hidden intentionally)

```
BTDevice
BTDevice
BTDevice
```

Comment: put out some code as well

Comment: Code is very simple. I have added it.